# Stop IRegisteredObjects in self-hosted ServiceStack (on Mono)

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, mono, servicestack

[Here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux#service-example) is an example how to listen to Unix signals and stop ServiceStack host.

If I have [IRegisteredObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject(v=vs.110).aspx)s running in this applications how can I ensure that all IRegisteredObjects receive proper Stop(false) and then Stop(true) calls, and how I can wait until all Stop(true) calls return?

Should I call `HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdown` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.initiateshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx))?

In IIS I just rely on the environment, but I am not sure if that functionality is possible at all with self-hosted ServiceStack.

(The question assumes that AWS platform sends SIGTERM before terminating spot instances at least in majority of cases. If AWS just kills instances, IRegisteredObjects are meaningless).